# Multithreaded servers setup

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am working on trying to get two servers communicating with each other. I know that I need to use threads but I cannot figure out how to set it up. I have been looking over many things that only discuss client/server interactions where the server sets up a ServerSocket on a port and the client connects to that port and can send messages to the server through the output stream.

What I've currently got is a class (Router, acting as the server) that creates a thread and within the run() method I've got

```
socket = server.accept();
...
while(...)
   String line = streamIn.readUTF();
...
```

Further down in my main method I ask for command line input about which server it wants to connect to and then take the entered IP and port and connect. I don't know how to get input and output from the server in this scenario.

Is there a better way to go about trying to get two servers to connect?

Thank you!

edit: All I am trying to do here is get Server/Server communication on the same computer. I'll run the program on port 6666 and then run the same program on 7777. I want to be able to connect these two so that they can communicate with each other.

Comment: I'm not sure what the real question is here.  Sockets are a fine way to have two programs communicate; it does involve a certain amount of low-level programming, since the sockets just give you streams of bytes.  On the other hand, they are a fine way to understand what is happening under the covers of the canned systems mentioned in another post.  But if you really don't know how to "set it up", perhaps you need a socket tutorial, not a stackoverflow answer.  If you have something more specific, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start from the back:

> Is there a better way to go about trying to get two servers to connect?

Absolutely.  The easiest path would be to take any JMS system like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), then use that to solve your problem.  This solves a lot of very hard problems for you, and makes your entire system more robust.  (Plus, code you don't write has a lot less bugs than code you do.)

Alternately, [Java RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) is a fine choice for invoking methods remotely, or you could dig out [MessagePack RPC](http://msgpack.org/), or [Protocol Buffers based RPC](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns#RPC_Implementations) to implement your operations.

Finally, HTTP is an awesome choice for this.  Seriously, there are so many excellent HTTP client and server choices available that you can embed in your Java application, and which will solve so many of these problems for you.

> I am working on trying to get two servers communicating with each other. I know that I need to use threads but I cannot figure out how to set it up.

Why do you think you need threads?  More specifically, think about what parts of the system need to be waiting and listening for messages, or sending them, concurrently with other parts of the system.

Then, and only then, add threads to meet those needs.  (Ideally, only if you can't solve the problem with non-blocking or callback based solutions.)

Anyway, my advice to you: don't write this yourself.  Use an existing solution.  It will hurt a lot less.

Comment: Well I am working on this for a project. It isn't for actual use but more of just learning how this stuff works. I'm trying to learn this stuff (but much simpler than what I think you were talking about) so I'm working on getting it together. Client/Server communication is a cinch but its the Server/Server communication thats is giving me issues.

Comment: Treat the problem as two client/server interactions, then, and you should be fine.  If necessary, consider where you need concurrency to allow each to act as a (blocking) client while still doing useful work.